# How to optimize for loops in extremely large dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe "x" with 5.9 million rows and 4 columns: idnumber/integer, compdate/integer and judge/character,, representing individual cases completed in an administrative court.  The data was imported from a stata dataset and the date field came in as integer, which is fine for my purposes.  I want to create the caseload variable by calculating the number of cases completed by the judge within the 30 day window of the completion date of the case at issue.

here are the first 34 rows of data:

```
idnumber    compdate    judge
1   9615    JVC
2   15316   BAN
3   15887   WLA
4   11968   WFN
5   15001   CLR
6   13914   IEB
7   14760   HSD
8   11063   RJD
9   10948   PPL
10  16502   BAN
11  15391   WCP
12  14587   LRD
13  10672   RTG
14  11864   JCW
15  15071   GMR
16  15082   PAM
17  11697   DLK
18  10660   ADP
19  13284   ECC
20  13052   JWR
21  15987   MAK
22  10105   HEA
23  14298   CLR
24  18154   MMT
25  10392   HEA
26  10157   ERH
27  9188    RBR
28  12173   JCW
29  10234   PAR
30  10437   ADP
31  11347   RDW
32  14032   JTZ
33  11876   AMC
34  11470   AMC
```

Here's what I came up with. So for each record I'm taking a subset of the data for that particular judge and then subsetting the cases decided in the 30 day window, and then assigning the length of a vector in the subsetted dataframe to the caseload variable for the subject case, as follows:

```
for(i in 1:length(x$idnumber)){
  e<-x$compdate[i]
  f<-e-29
  a<-x[x$judge==x$judge[i] & !is.na(x$compdate),]
  b<-a[a$compdate<=e & a$compdate>=f,]
  x$caseload[i]<-length(b$idnumber)
}
```

It is working but it is taking extremely long to complete. How can I optimize this or do this easier.  Sorry I'm very new to r and to programming -- I'm a law professor trying to analyze court data....  Your help is appreciated.  Thanks.
Ken

Comment: You made a pretty good start on the question, but it would be very helpful if you included a sample `data.frame` with only a few rows (like 10). That way, we can run your code, and our new code against the `data.frame` and verify that it is the same.

Comment: The "previous 30 days" business might be a little strange, because the number of business days in the prior 30 (real) days will vary within a week. Maybe you should do it week to week? By the way, I don't know that "window" automatically means "30 previous days", instead of "30 subsequent days" or "15 on either side". You don't specify outside of the math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have much experience with rolling calculations, but...

- Calculate this per-day, not per-case (since it will be the same for cases on the same day).
- Calculate a cumulative sum of the number of cases, and then take the difference of the current value of this sum and the value of the sum 31 days ago (or `min{daysAgo:daysAgo>30}` since cases are not resolved every day).

It's probably fastest to use a data.table. This is my attempt, using @nograpes simulated data. Comments start with `#`.

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(x)
DT[,compdate:=as.integer(compdate)]
setkey(DT,judge,compdate)

# count cases for each day
ldt <- DT[,.N,by='judge,compdate']
# cumulative sum of counts
ldt[,nrun:=cumsum(N),by=judge]
# see how far to look back
ldt[,lookbk:=sapply(1:.N,function(i){
    z       <-  compdate[i]-compdate[i:1]
    older   <-  which(z>30)
    if (length(older)) min(older)-1L else as(NA,'integer')
}),by=judge]
# compute cumsum(today) - cumsum(more than 30 days ago)
ldt[,wload:=list(sapply(1:.N,function(i)
    nrun[i]-ifelse(is.na(lookbk[i]),0,nrun[i-lookbk[i]])
))]
```

On my laptop, this takes under a minute. Run this command to see the output for one judge:

```
print(ldt['XYZ'],nrow=120)
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to loop through every row. You can do operations on the entire column at once. First, create some data:

```
# Create some data.
n<-6e6 # cases
judges<-apply(combn(LETTERS,3),2,paste0,collapse='') # About 2600 judges
set.seed(1)
x<-data.frame(idnumber=1:n,judge=sample(judges,n,replace=TRUE),compdate=Sys.Date()+round(runif(n,1,120)))
```

Now, you can make a rolling window function, and run it on each judge.

```
# Sort
x<-x[order(x$judge,x$compdate),]
# Create a little rolling window function.
rolling.window<-function(y,window=30) seq_along(y) - findInterval(y-window,y)
# Run the little function on each judge.
x$workload<-unlist(by(x$compdate,x$judge,rolling.window)))
```